# Change Visio default drawing units

Tags: c#, visio

I'm using a axdrawingcontrol with c# to open Visio. I need to change the default drawing units (which are inches?) to points. The rulers and the grid are already in points but if I use e.g `ActivePage.DrawRectangle(1, 5, 5, 1);` method the rectangle is drawn in inches.

I tried following code to change the default units but it had no effect. Where is my mistake?

```
AxDrawingControl _drawingControl;
_drawingControl.Document.Application.ActivePage.PageSheet.CellsSRC[
                    (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject ,
                    (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPage,
                    (short)VisCellIndices.visPageScale
                    ].FormulaU ="1pt";
                _drawingControl.Document.Application.ActivePage.PageSheet.CellsSRC[
                    (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                    (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPage,
                    (short)VisCellIndices.visPageDrawingScale
                    ].FormulaU = "1pt";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page.DrawRectangle` always draws in inches (aka "internal units"), you can't change that.

Check out [this topic](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5282.0) for details and workarounds.

Comment: thanks a lot. so i have to write some methods to draw in points. but still it is easier with new methods instead of converting  "inches /72.0" it each time.